# Get average from inner table's result set

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to get the average per week. To do this i first count the daily occurences in a subquery and group by the day. Then I want to average each day and group them based off week number. However it does not give the expected result.

```
select avg(d.dayilyCount)
from (
      select count(*) as dayilyCount, timestamp as inner_T 
            from steps 
                group by strftime('%D', timestamp / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')
) d 
  group by strftime('%W', d.inner_T/ 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')
```

Any tips?

Thanks

EDIT:

Sample data and result i want:

```
-time-steps-
Day 1|Step 1|
Day 1|Step 1|
Day 2|Step 1|
Day 2|Step 1|
Day 2|Step 1|

-time-count-       this is the subquery
Day 1|Step 2|<----imagine this is week 1
Day 2|Step 3|<----imagine this is week 4
```

then I want average per week and group by the week the timestamp returned by the inner tables count.

```
time  |avg      what I want
week 1| 1.0
week 4| 3.0
```

what I get:

```
time  |avg  
week n| 4.0
```

I only get one result instead of two even though I have different weeks counted and grouped by in the inner result set.

EDIT 2:

I found out the issue, I used capital D instead of '%d' in the strftime() function

```
 select avg(d.dayilyCount) 
from(
select count(*) as dayilyCount, timestamp as dt, strftime('%d-%W-%m-%Y',     timestamp / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as dwmy from steps group by dwmy
) d
group by strftime('%W-%m-%Y', d.dt / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')
```

plus i didnt group by a specific day, year or month which it also should have done.

Comment: i added an explanation. Ill try to rewrite it better, but for now its that.

Comment: Much better, but could you show the actual data you're using to get the 4.0 result (basically, a `SELECT dayilyCount, timestamp FROM steps`)?

Comment: i found out the issue. i used %D instead of %d so it returned null. I updated the op. It gives the desired result atleast.